# How to calculate $f(x, y, z)$ given $d f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy +\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms

On a manifold with local coordinates $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ I have a closed 1-form $\omega$ for which $d \omega = 0$ holds. This means
There must be a function $f(x_1, \ldots x_n)$ for which $d f = \omega$.

My question is, how to calculate this function $f$, only given the coefficients of $\omega$.

Example $\omega = dx_1 + \sin(x_3)dx_2 + x_2 \cos(x_3)dx_3$.

Of course, this example is solvable by a sharp look, but I look for an algorithm.

(In fact I already have one but it seems to complicated.)

Comment: Closedness of a form only guarantees that it is *locally* the exterior derivative of some function; consider $$\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}(-y \,dx + x \,dy),$$ which is (for purposes of this explanation, somewhat unfortunately) sometimes denoted $d\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to calculate $f$ locally. So take a chart whose image is a ball  which contains $0$ and identify it with a neighborhood of $x\in M$ you have:

$f(x)=\int_0^t\omega_{tx}(x)dt$.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But, I still do not know how to actually "execute" the integral. And (maybe related) I do not understand the notation $\omega_{tx}(x)$.

Comment: Locally $\omega =df$, $\omega$ is a $1$-form defined on a ball of $R^n$ so if $t$ is a real and $x\in R^n$, you can consider $\omega_{tx}$ which is an element of the dual of the tangent space of $tx$ viewed as an element of $R^n$. So $\int_0^1\omega_{tx}(x)dt=\int_0^tdf_{tx}(x)dt=f(tx)]_0^1$ since the differential of $t\rightarrow f(tx)$ is $df_{tx}(x)$ if you use the fact that locally $\omega=df$.

Comment: In fact $f(x)=\int _[0x] \omega = \int _0^1 <w(tx),x> dt= \int _0^1 a(tx,ty,tz)x+b (tx,ty,tz)y+c(tx,ty,tz)z dt$ if $\omega= adx+bdy+cdz$ . In fact, $f$ is the integral of the form $\omega$ on the path $[0,x]$

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you really need to compute, either integrating (you know that integrals along any path with same initial and final points are equal), or solving:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=1, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=\sin(x_3),\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}=x_2\cos{x_3},.
$$
The computational difficulty is the same with both "methods". Certainly the same comment applies to any other example.

Comment: I know that I can integrate each of the partial derivatives. However, I do not know how to handle the results. In the example integratinging yields $F_1 = x_1 + C_1$, $F_2 = x_2 \sin(x_3)$, $F_3 = x_2 \sin (x_3) + C_3$. Obviously adding everything does not help.

Comment: @basweber As usual: from the first $f(x)=x_1+g(x_2,x_3)$, replace in the others to get for example $\partial g/\partial x_2=\sin x_3$, integrate to get $g(x_2,x_3)=-\cos x_3+h(x_2)$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general method for finding an antiderivative of a closed differential form defined on a star-shaped region (more generally, on some region $D$ that’s the image of a star-shaped region) that’s particularly simple in the case of a one-form. It’s basically the same as what’s described in [Tsemo Aristide’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1648398/265466), elsewhere.

*Step 1:* Replace $x^i$ with $tx^i$ in the arguments of all the coefficient functions and $\mathrm{d}x^i$ with $x^i\,\mathrm{d}t$. (In the general case, make the replacement $\mathrm{d}x^i\to x^i\,\mathrm{d}t+t\,\mathrm{d}x^i$ instead.)

*Step 2:* Treat the $\mathrm{d}t$ as an ordinary integral, and integrate w/r $t$ from $0$ to $1$.

For a general differential form, there’s also an intermediate step, in which you discard all terms not involving $\mathrm{d}t$ and move $\mathrm{d}t$ to the left in the remaining terms, taking care to get the signs right.

In your case, you have $$\omega = \mathrm{d}x_1 + \sin x_3\,\mathrm{d}x_2 + x_2 \cos x_3\,\mathrm{d}x_3.$$
Step 1 produces $$x_1\,\mathrm{d}t + x_2\sin{tx_3}\,\mathrm{d}t + tx_2x_3\cos{tx_3}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ and integrating with respect to $t$ yields $$\int_0^1x_1+x_2\sin{tx_3}+tx_2x_3\cos{tx_3}\,\mathrm{d}t = x_1+x_2\sin{x_3}.$$  As for why this method works in general, that takes more explaining than I care to do here.